# JOIN 2 tables with degrading conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I have to join 2 tables (Oracle): **A** & **B**  by several columns:

```
A.C1 = B.C1 
A.C2 = B.C2
```

and if the condition fails then I should try to join with less demanding condition

```
A.C1 = B.C1
```

will it work for me correctly:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM A JOIN B ON 
   (A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2) OR (A.C1 = B.C1)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your query is equivalent to `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM A JOIN B ON A.C1 = B.C1` as the other condition is a subset of this one.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - not yet. There may be several records in B with A.C1 = B.C1 and only one of them with A.C2 = B.C2. In this case, I'll fetch this single record. If I'll simplify my condition to A.C1 = B.C1 then I'll get all mentioned records. Am I right?

Comment: No, because OR is inclusive - you will get all the records in B with `A.C1 = B.C1` and the one record with `A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2`, which you would have got anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
  FROM A JOIN B ON 
    ON (A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2)
    OR (A.C1 = B.C1 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B
                                   WHERE (A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2)
                                  )
       )
```

This should ensure that if there are records matching (A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 = B.C2) then you don't get any "second best" records where (A.C1 = B.C1 AND A.C2 != B.C2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use two left joins:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.col, bdef.col)
from a left join
     b
     on a.c1 = b.c1 and a.c2 = b.c2 left join
     b bdef
     on a.c1 = bdef.c1 and b.c1 is null;
```

You might want `where b.c1 is not null or bdef.c1 is not null` if there are cases where neither matches -- and you want to filter them out.